# SSIS Designer and splitting Packages

Tags: sql, ssis

I have a large solution which is currently in 1 big package.  I've started to split the package into smaller packages but have noticed that more memory is being used on the SQL Server when running the solution.

Has anyone else seen this when using multiple packages?

Comment: SQL server is using more memory or dtexec.exe is using more memory when the packages are running? With the split to multiple packages, are you running them in parallel or serial?

Comment: I'm not sure TBH - the server memory is reaching it's limit. (3.7GB of 4GB).
All the packages are run serially.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server, sqlservr.exe, is generally run as a service and as you use it, it's going to continue consuming memory until it's sucked it all and windows forces it back down. That's by design as the database performs best when it has as much data as possible in memory vs having to read from disk. You should [configure your SQL Server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/152720/sql-server-memory-allocation-and-max-server-memory-setting) instance to have a maximum memory so that the OS can have room to breathe. [How much memory should you reserve?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69639/when-should-i-not-set-the-maximum-server-memory-option-in-sql-server)

SQL Server Integration Services, SSIS, runs in its own address space - even though you can launch it from SQL Server you'll see it, dtexec.exe, handles asking for memory and in the event the process crashes, it does not bring down SQL Server. This is a very good thing, the separation. From a practical perspective, it means that if you are going to run SSIS packages on a machine, you need to leave enough memory for SSIS to run and guess what, SSIS is a blazing fast `in-memory` ETL solution. As much as it can, an SSIS data flow task is going to hold data in its memory so it can manipulate it (change data type, lookup, etc) in one big pass before writing it to destination as the IO is the most expensive part of ETL.

But, as you're developing these packages, you're running them from Visual Studio, devenv.exe. VS/SSDT needs memory to do its thing. And hey, when you run an SSIS package from Visual Studio, that's wrapped in the debugger call (can't recall the process name) and that too sucks memory to be able to provide debugging capability.

Sadly, a four gigabyte allocation of RAM for a developer machine is insufficient. And if this is a server, the licensing cost alone dwarfs what it'd cost to max that box out on memory.

Were it me, I'd cap SQL Server about 1.5 GB. Under a gig is usually not enough for SQL Server to do much of anything. Assume that Visual Studio and the debugger are going to be good for about 2 gigs when things get hot and heavy. That leaves .5 gigs reserved to the OS (and Outlook, Excel, Windows Explorer, Web browser pointed at StackOverflow and MSDN documentation and crap, we're out of memory)

To address memory usage by SSIS. I would think but have not tested, that 1 package with 10 data flow connected serially versus 10 packages with 1 data flow each, the monolithic package would consume more memory as it will validate all the data flows when it starts. Yes, there is startup overhead that is shared by the monolithic approach which will be allocated for each individual package but I can't imagine it will be of any significance. Plus, that memory is returned to the OS once the dtexec process completes. It is not like SQL Server which will hold on to the memory until the process cycles.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I'm referring to the server memory having 4GB, not my local machine (which has 6GB(!)).  

There are no issues running the solution locally in Visual Studio or on the Server itself.  I just wondered if there is more memory used if there are more packages in the solution.  Saying that I am doing the package split anyway to improve readability and supportability.